# What would influence two or many photons to collide and create an electron-positron fermion pair?

Tags: photons, fermions

If there were billions of photons around in nothing - no gravity, no electromagnetic fields, etc., what (if anything) would cause the photons to interact in a way that would cause a collision potentially creating an electron-positron pair or any other pair of fermions?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this proposal for a [gamma gamma collider](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf) . It has the calculations needed , crossections and fluxes necessary so that the photon photon interactions could take place.

Your photon soup needs enough density so that the probability of a photon to interact with another photon becomes large enough for pair production to occur, if the energy of the photons is sufficient.

One can use this  e+e- annihilation Feynman diagram, taking the time dimension from right to left:

[image: e+e-]

A photon in the soup has to scatter off another photon if the energy is enough there will be a probability to  produce an e+e- pair.